# "conflicting implementations" error in complex generic code, how to fix it?

Tags: rust

I have `Base` trait, implement `Foo<B>` for all type that implemented `Bar<B>`, now I want to special implement `Foo<B>` for all `Foobar<B>` struct, where `B: Base`:

```
trait Base {}


trait Foo<B: Base> {}


trait Bar<B: Base> {}


struct Foobar<B: Base> { _b: B }


// delete either, compile success
impl<B: Base, T: Bar<B>> Foo<B> for T {}
impl<B: Base> Foo<B> for Foobar<B> {}


fn main()
{
}
```

The compile error is:

```
<anon>:14:1: 14:41 error: conflicting implementations for trait `Foo` [E0119]
<anon>:14 impl<B: Base, T: Bar<B>> Foo<B> for T {}
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:14:1: 14:41 help: see the detailed explanation for E0119
<anon>:15:1: 15:38 note: note conflicting implementation here
<anon>:15 impl<B: Base> Foo<B> for Foobar<B> {}
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8ccb9def1f010ed7625d&version=nightly)

Comment: you can't. There's an RFC to allow it though: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your impls are overlapping and there is no general fix to this (other than "avoid the blanket impl if you want to specialize it later").

Having the possibility to have a more specialized version of the impl is currently in [a RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210). An attempt at implementation is in [this pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/30652).