# Is there some way to implement a trait on multiple traits?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Why doesn't this work:

```
trait Update {
    fn update(&mut self);
}

trait A {}
trait B {}

impl<T: A> Update for T {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        println!("A")
    }
}

impl<U: B> Update for U {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        println!("B")
    }
}
```

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Update`:
  --> src/main.rs:14:1
   |
8  | impl<T: A> Update for T {
   | ----------------------- first implementation here
...
14 | impl<U: B> Update for U {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation
```

I would assume it is checked later if types overlap.

Comment: You are expected to mention what goes wrong when compiling that code. In this case, it doesn't compile due to conflicting implementations. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35127870/1233251

Comment: There is lots of discussion on this topic, eg https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1053 .  There is work going on to make this or something like it possible, but at the moment overlapping impls like that are not legal.

Comment: This can't work, even with Specialisation. To see why, consider a struct that implements both `A` and `B`. What output would you expect when you call `update()` on it?  With Specialisation, the "most specific" implementation would be used, but here `A` and `B` are completely equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What would you expect the output of this program to be?

```
struct AAndB {}
impl A for AAndB {}
impl B for AAndB {}

let a_and_b = AAndB {};
a_and_b.update();
```

There is an unstable compiler feature, [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844), which you can enable in nightly builds, which lets you have overlapping instances, and the most "specialized" is used.

But, even with specialization enabled, your example won't work because `A` and `B` are completely equivalent so you could never unambiguously pick an instance.

As soon as there is an obviously "more specialized" instance, it will compile and work as expected - provided you are using a *nightly* build of Rust with specialization enabled. For example, if one of the traits is bounded by the other, then it is more specialized, so this would work:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait Update {
    fn update(&mut self);
}

trait A {}
trait B: A {}

impl<T: A> Update for T {
    default fn update(&mut self) {
        println!("A")
    }
}

impl<U: B> Update for U {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        println!("B")
    }
}
```

Specifying the implementation method as `default` allows another more specific implementation to define its own version of the method.

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't even work, when different structs implement both traits. But it may also be nice, when a struct is able to implement both, like you wrote, and then is able to call both. The struct would require to impl Update itself and call the less specific versions, manually, so this would also just be suboptimal.

Comment: The [link](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1053), which Chris Emerson left in the other comments, describes a few other potential enhancements to how overlapping instances might work in the future. Some possibilities are [negative bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/586), or [mutually exclusive traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1148). If either of these were ever implemented, you could make a guarantee to the compiler that there could never be an ambiguity.