# Conflict implementation in trait 'Factory'

Tags: rust, traits

```
fn home(name:String) -> String {
  name
}

fn index() -> String {
  "Hello".to_string()
}

trait Factory {}

impl<T> Factory for T where T: Fn() -> String {

}

impl<T> Factory for T where T: Fn(String) -> String {

}

struct User {}

impl User {
  fn get<F>(factory: F) where F: Factory {

  }
}
fn main() {
  User::get(index);
  User::get(home);
}
```

Hey guys I am having this issue wherein rust compiler complains about trait implementation conflicts. The issue occurs when i write this piece of code "impl Factory for T where T: Fn(String) -> String". Please help. Any suggestions to resolve this issue will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there some way to implement a trait on multiple traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426239/is-there-some-way-to-implement-a-trait-on-multiple-traits)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? While technically `index` and `home` are function pointers, and not closures. The reason you can't do that, is because even though a closure could be `Fn(String) -> String`. That technically doesn't prevent it from also implementing `Fn() -> String`. Which is related to variadic closures.

Comment: I tried using macro_rules! to solve my problem. And it does work for me. But I do not understand why above code does not work.